Power Query Copy Child Data to Parent in Hierarchy
I have a table with parent/child hierarchy where the values in the children in a column (BinNum) needs to be propagated or copied over to the parent. Is there a way to do this in Power Query or DAX?
Input and Result Table:



Level
Sequence
BinNum

Level
Sequence
BinNum




A10
1
0

A10
1
50


A10
2
0

A10
2
243


A10
3
0

A10
3
100


A10
4
0

A10
4
67


A10
5
0

A10
5
98


A10-05
1
0

A10-05
1
50


A10-05
2
0

A10-05
2
243


A10-05
3
0

A10-05
3
100


A10-05
4
0

A10-05
4
67


A10-05
5
0

A10-05
5
98


A10-05-01
1
50

A10-05-01
1
50


A10-05-01
2
243

A10-05-01
2
243


A10-05-01
3
100

A10-05-01
3
100


A10-05-01
4
67

A10-05-01
4
67


A10-05-01
5
98

A10-05-01
5
98


A10-06
1
0

A10-06
1
50


A10-06
2
0

A10-06
2
243


A10-06
3
0

A10-06
3
100


A10-06
4
0

A10-06
4
67


A10-06
5
0

A10-06
5
98


A10-06-01
1
50

A10-06-01
1
50


A10-06-01
2
243

A10-06-01
2
243


A10-06-01
3
100

A10-06-01
3
100


A10-06-01
4
67

A10-06-01
4
67


A10-06-01
5
98

A10-06-01
5
98



Input Table and Result Table

If BinNum for A10-06-01 different from BinNum for A10-05-01, what values get carried back to A10?

Please don't use images for data tables.

@MayukhBhattacharya thank you for editing and pasting the data table. I will use the generator you provided next time. Apologies for the inconvenience to all.

You can try this, which is a simple single step merge. It assumes both Level and Sequence are part of the match
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Level],"-")),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([BinNum] <> 0)),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"Sequence", "Custom"}),

#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"BinNum"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"Custom", "Sequence"}, #"Removed Duplicates", {"Custom", "Sequence"}, "Table1 (3)", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1 (3)", {"BinNum"}, {"BinNum"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Expanded,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index", "Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"

